# How do I change the width from a responsive Button in UI5?

Tags: responsive-design, sapui5

I'm a UI5 beginner and I want to create two responsive sap.m.Buttons. The width should be 50% of the view per Button. The problem is, I don't really get how to set the width for a responsive button.

```
    var oButtonNeuePal = new sap.m.Button({
        icon : "sap-icon://add-document",
        text : "{i18n>lieferschein.btnNeuePal}",
        press : [ 'NEUEPAL', oController.onButton, oController ]
    });
    var oButtonProtokoll = new sap.m.Button({
        icon : "sap-icon://list",
        text : "{i18n>lieferschein.btnProtokoll}",
        press : [ 'PROTOKOLL', oController.onButton, oController ]
    });


    /***********************************************************************
     * Page
     */     

    var oForm = new sap.ui.layout.form.SimpleForm({
        layout : sap.ui.layout.form.SimpleFormLayout.ResponsiveGridLayout
    });

    var oGroupH = new sap.m.HBox({
        justifyContent : sap.m.FlexJustifyContent.SpaceBetween,
    });
    oGroupH.addItem(oButtonNeuePal);
    oGroupH.addItem(oButtonProtokoll);

    var oGroupV = new sap.m.VBox();
    oGroupV.addItem(oGroupH);
    //I removed some labels and Inputfield

    oForm.addContent(oGroupV);

    var oPage = new sap.m.Page({
        customHeader : oBar
    });
    oPage.addContent(oForm);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might be interesting for you: [Flex Box - Size Adjustments](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/entity/sap.m.FlexBox/sample/sap.m.sample.FlexBoxSizeAdjustments)

When filling a `HBox`/`FlexBox` with content, not every control (maybe even no control) will automatically take the whole available space.

You have to give the Button a `width` of 100% and set the `growFactor` of its layout to 1.

In XML (from my sample link):

```
<Button text="{i18n>lieferschein.btnNeuePal}" width="100%">
    <layoutData>
        <FlexItemData growFactor="1" />
    </layoutData>
</Button>
```

In JS (probably):

```
var oButtonNeuePal = new sap.m.Button({
    icon : "sap-icon://add-document",
    text : "{i18n>lieferschein.btnNeuePal}",
    layoutData: new sap.m.FlexItemData({ growFactor: 1}),
    width: "100%",
    press : [ 'NEUEPAL', oController.onButton, oController ]
});
```